# Calculating Mean of Column - TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the mean of a column in my dataframe, but I get the `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`
What am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('rawdata.csv')
mean = df.mean('Quantity')
```

I expect a single value: the mean of the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the column name in the wrong place. Try as below

```
mean = df['Quantity'].mean()
```